# How to find who put the sharepoint site collection in READ only mode in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have one SharePoint2010 site. Suddenly i saw today that site has been put into `READ` mode. How to audit, who has done this.

I want to know who put the site into READ only mode(through CA->Site quotas and locks).

Is there any way to find? (through powershell command, SPD, Database or through any other things)

Answer (score 3):

Locks can be Set/Reset in 6 ways:

- Using Web User Interface - Through Central Administration
- Using STSADM
- Using PowerShell
- Using Object Model
- By .Net code
- By PowerShell

Look at this link it will tell you everything with explanation and expamples

[/site-collection-locks-in-sharepoint](http://salaudeen.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/site-collection-locks-in-sharepoint.html)

or MSDN

[Site Collection Locks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263238.aspx)

Hope it helped ;)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. That is explaining how to put in READ only. Thats fine. But i would like to know who put the site in READ only. It might have done through CA UI or stsadm or powershell also. Anyway their Active directory account ID would have logged in Database right(using which account, it has done). We want to know that only.

Comment: you said 4, but your list has 6! :D

Comment: Another to add to your list: a site collection will be locked when a site collection backup runs. There used to be an issue in MOSS where sometimes it would not get unlocked after the backup (say for example the backup failed). It was common to force an unlock after running a site collection backup.

Comment: @shufler thanks for letting me know :D, you know sometimes yu think some and something else comes up Lol

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that happen occasionally when a site exceeds its quota so it is possible that SharePoint itself locked it.  If the site in question was at or near the quota, this could be what happened.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks for your reply. I checked the site quota and its very near. This worked.